# What are the benefits to using a debug macro rather than a simple function?

Tags: c, debugging

It seems that for `printf`-style debugging people always use preprocessor macros. Is there anything wrong with a solution similar to this one?

```
void debug(char *msg) {
#ifdef DEBUG
printf("%s", msg);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually so that they can do something like this:

```
#define DEBUG(MSG) printf("[%s:%i] %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, (MSG))
```

Since it's so useful to have the exact source of a debug message right there in the log, this is a pretty common pattern. But if you used a function, like so:

```
void DEBUG(const char *MSG) {
    printf("[%s:%i] %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, (MSG));
}
```

Then you'd only ever get to see the filename and line number corresponding to the `printf()` call in `DEBUG()`, and never those of the code that called `DEBUG()`.

Answer (score 3):

1) Your code will break if `msg` is `%d` or such, because printf expects a format string.  `printf("%s", msg);` is better.

2) Not really.  Macros are overused unless you're micro-optimizing (e.g. for code size).  Functions are easier to debug with since you can do stuff like `stop in debug` in your debugger.  There's a zillion other things that are tricky with macros.  See http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/c/Advice_and_Warnings_for_C/Macros_and_Miscellaneous_Pitfalls.html

3) As @Jonathan Grynspan pointed out - the macro form is easier to use with **FILE** , **LINE** .  In my opinion developers like taking shortcuts in typing that make their code harder to maintain for others later, and ironically harder to debug themselves later.  Best practice IMO:  type extra, make your code easy to debug and easy to run in a debugger, and use a function with signature `debug(const char* msg, const char* FILE_LOC, unsigned LINE_NUMBER)`

Comment: I have fixed my code as that error isn't really relevant to the question.

Comment: These aren't strong arguments for wrapping a simple call to `printf` inside another function. Given that the question is specifically about printf-style debugging, I don't think debugger use is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

If one uses a `DEBUG` macro, then changing a single #define statement or compilation option and recompiling can make all of the debug code vanish from the executable.  By contrast, if one uses a `DEBUG()` function, then every invocation will generate code to call the function, whether or not the function itself does anything.

Comment: Will it? I'd assume that the compiler would optimize that function call away, at least if I keep the debug function in the same file object as the actual code.

Comment: A good compiler will optimize away the calls to the empty function. However, the compiler cannot eliminate the function completely; as declared, it has external scope, so the compiler must include it in the object file, in case some code from another module calls it. (A good linker might eliminate it later.) And, if it is defined in multiple source modules, the linker will complain about multiple definitions. Declaring the function "static" allows the compiler to eliminate the definition.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the use of `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, you should also compare the following:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
    #define DEBUG_PRINT(...) ((void)0)
#else
    #define DEBUG_PRINT(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Against your function:

```
void debug(const char* msg) {
    #ifndef NDEBUG
        printf("%s", msg);
    #endif
}
```

With the macro, I can write:

```
DEBUG_PRINT("Expected %d, got %d\n", correct_value, result);
```

With the function, I have to go to some effort to construct one or more strings using my integers, and call the function one or more times. In release mode the function does nothing, so the string is unused. The optimizer *might* manage to eliminate the code to construct it, or then again it might not. With the macro there's no doubt.

That said, you could write your `debug` function to do the right thing with varargs. But your function as written will hit this problem eventually, and you'll have to add a `debugf`.